# In reactjs how can I call a method from another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Just trying reactjs and came across the situation that I want to call a method on another component:

```
class MyComp extends React.Component {

callMe(){
...
       }
}
```

So mycomp2:

```
import MyComp from 'myComp';

class MyComp2 extends React.Component {

test(){
       MyComp.callMe();
      }
}
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: you can always take out a modular function to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the method **callMe** doesn't use **this**, you can declear it as **static** to use it like that.

```
class MyComp extends React.Component {

    static callMe(){
    ...
    }
}
```

If not, you can use **ref** to make it work.

You may need:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: OP: While this answers your question, the need for this behaviour is rare in idiomatic React code, so I would suggest that it would be a good idea to post more code and what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot. You cannot do that in react component. The only way is to move that function to their common ancestor.

Of course, there is another way, why not consider redux? let's react component talk through redux state. that way, you will never have this puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your components are related to one another.  If one is a parent and the other is a child then the function can be passed as a prop from parent to child, e.g.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    callMe() {
        console.log('called');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Child doSomething={() => this.callMe()} />
        );
    }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
    render() {
         <button onClick={this.props.doSomething}>Calls the parent fn</button>
    }
}
```

Alternatively if they are not a parent-child relationship, then you need to introduce a parent component in which the function can live, then pass it via props in the same way.

If neither of these approaches seems to fit, then let us know what behaviour you are trying to achieve that requires this, and there my well be a different way to structure your code.